# position of images are wrong in animated photo banner

Tags: banner, animated

I am using [this](http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/photobanner/index.html) animated banner in my website.

Now I've copied the exact code from the tutorial but for some reason in my [version](http://www.gmbelt.com/index.html) the images seemed to be placed at the bottom of the table and cut off instead of as in the example. I've tried a number of possible solutions but either I've done them in the wrong place or they just don't work.

Normally I would add in the code but in this case (as you'll see from view page source) it's too long to post.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just opened Chrome Inspector changed few css properties and it worked. Here they are...

```
.photobanner 
{
    height: 232px;
    width: 984px;
}
#container2 
{
    width: 748px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background: white;
}
```

I guess this would work.Tested in chrome..try your self with other browser and you should reduce margin of `<h1>` tag

Comment: That does seem to help with the positioning of the images (I will however have to adjust the size of it) but now the only problem is that it doesn't scroll like it should in the tutorial http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/photobanner/index.html it just scrolls to the last image and then "jumps" to the first image again instead continually scrolling.

Comment: You should have posted the demo version on the same link. I went over there and nothing was there. well as i suggested you need to adjust the width of the container and it will work. I was having same problem and solved it by just changing the width.
<br/> Hope it works! :)

Comment: I found out that this code doesn't work in internet explorer (which it needs to) so I'm going to be using a different code now, but thanks for the help as it did help, just not in IE.

Comment: Well, My experience suggest when you go for any kind of plugin or jQuery selection, Search it in IE. Anything working in IE will always works in other browsers as well. except few things which is only supported in IE not in other browsers such as ActiveX.

Comment: I've found something that works in IE now and it works great in the other browsers. I'll mark this answer as an accepted answer, as although I ended up not using this actual code, it did help when i needed it.